# filename string search using fnmatch()

Tags: php

Assuming I have a file on my directory called `table.pdf` and i'm trying to make a search using the string `table` as a search criteria. I have tried to do this using `fnmatch()` with `table` as my `$pattern` but this doesn;t return a match whereas using `table.pdf` as the `$pattern` returns a match. Example

```
$table = 'table';
$table_2 = 'table.pdf';
if (fnmatch($table, $pdf)){
// No Match found
}
if (fnmatch($table_2, $pdf)){
// Match Found
}
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: Hi, according to the documentation, the **pattern** is a shell like string, if you want to use the first pattern you should go for : "table*" if you want to match all "table" files. If you were meaning to have a generic pdf string you should go for "*.pdf".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
$table = 'table*';
$table_2 = 'table.pdf';
if (fnmatch($table, $pdf)){
// No Match found
}
if (fnmatch($table_2, $pdf)){
// Match Found
}
```